# Running TensorFlow label_image example throws access violation

Tags: tensorflow

I verified that the path to the binary protobuf file (inception_v3_2016_08_28_frozen.pb) is correct.  In the `LoadGraph` function, `ReadBinaryProto` appears to succeed (`load_graph_status` passes the ok check), but the call to Session->Create using the resulting graph_def throws an exception:

> "Exception thrown: read access violation
>   session->_Mypair._Myval2 was nullptr."

If I examine the `graph_def` object, it doesn't really appear to contain anything (`version_` is 0, `_cached_size_` is 0, all pointers appear to be NULL, etc.).

Answer (score 1):

Resolving this required adding the Visual Studio /WHOLEARCHIVE flag to a bunch of the TF libary files.  The ones I ended up whole archiving (some may not be strictly necessary) were:

```
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_protos_cc.lib
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_c.lib
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_cc.lib
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_cc_framework.lib
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_cc_ops.lib
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_cc_while_loop.lib
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_core_cpu.lib
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_core_direct_session.lib
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_core_framework.lib
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_core_kernels.lib
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_core_lib.lib
/WHOLEARCHIVE:tf_core_ops.lib
```